# Browser disabled after logout in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The admin controller I have:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('common');
    $this->load->library('session');


    }

    public function index(){       
       $this->load->view("login");

    }
   public function matched(){
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass','Password','required');
                if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                $error['error']=validation_errors();
                $this->load->view('login',$error);

  }
        else{
                $name= $this->input->post('name');
                $pass=$this->input->post('pass');
                $result=$this->common->match_data($name,$pass);
                if(!empty($result)){   
                  $data=array(
                              'id'=>$result[0]->id,
                              'name'=>$result[0]->name,
                              'type'=>$result[0]->type,
                              'logged_in'=>TRUE
                              );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data); 

                redirect('dashboard');
  }
          else{
            $this->load->view('login');

  }

  }
  }

public function logoutuser(){
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
                redirect("admin","refresh");

  }  

}

?>
```

Dashboard Controller :

```
    <?php
class Dashboard extends CI_controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('common');
    }


public function index(){
$this->load->view('dashboard');
}

}

?>
```

Dashboard page or view page:

```
<?php
//echo "<pre>";print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit;

$name=$this->session->userdata('name');
$id=$this->session->userdata('id');
$type=$this->session->userdata('type');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin - Bootstrap Admin Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><?php echo "User"."-".ucwords($type); ?></a>



            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu message-dropdown">
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong><?php echo $name;?></strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong><?php echo $name;?></strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong><?php echo $name;?></strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-footer">
                            <a href="#">Read All New Messages</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-default">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-primary">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-success">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-info">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-warning">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-danger">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">View All</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo $name;?><b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/logoutuser"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">

                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Charts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="bootstrap-elements.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i> Bootstrap Elements</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="bootstrap-grid.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> Bootstrap Grid</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Dropdown <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Blank Page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index-rtl.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> RTL Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Dashboard <small>Statistics Overview</small>
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->


                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

problem is that when i am clicking on the browser back button its take me back on logged in user ..ever time i need to disable browser back button using codeigniter without using javascript

Comment: check `session variable` in your controller

Comment: can u update my code ??

Comment: unquoted the actual question

Answer (score 0):

Disabling back button of browser is not possible in codeigniter.
While there is alternative ways of Redirecting user upon destroying session to that page which we want.

check session variable in your view,controller is it working..

```
echo $_SESSION['session_varibalename'];
```

Also you can see this link too: [how to disable the back button in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963661/how-to-disable-the-back-button-in-codeigniter)

```
<?php
class Dashboard extends CI_controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('common');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }


public function index(){
    $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if($logged_in == TRUE || empty($logged_in))
    {
        //user not logged in
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Session has Expired');
        //it will redirect the user to the Admin controller to index function which will call the login view.
        redirect('Admin/index'); 
    }
    else
    {
        //user Logged in
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check session in your controller

```
 <?php
class Dashboard extends CI_controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('common');
         $this->load->library('session');
    }


public function index(){
if($this->session->all_userdata()){
$this->load->view('dashboard');
}
else{
redirect('lofin_contoller');
}
}

}

?>
```